# Meta tags aren't showing for sub pages in whatsapp - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, whatsapp, meta-tags

My meta tags works great. However, when shared on whatsapp, only the main page shows the `og:image` and `description`. Every sub-page is just showing the link.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My Title">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Website Name">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://websiteLink.co.il" />
<meta name="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://websiteLink.com/websiteLogo.png">
```

I'm using react with react router dom. I checked every page and the meta tags stay the same as the main page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: WhatsApp typically caches the meta tags when a link is first shared, and subsequent pages might not update the cached information. To address this issue, you can try adding a unique parameter, like a timestamp or version number, to the URL when sharing sub-pages. This can prompt WhatsApp to fetch and display the updated meta tags for each sub-page.

For example, instead of sharing:
`https://websiteLink.co.il/subpage`

Share:
`https://websiteLink.co.il/subpage?v=1`

This can help ensure that WhatsApp fetches the latest meta tags for each sub-page.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I still only see the link. Could it be because WhatsApp takes time to update the tags?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, justyce jaelen!

Your 7 answers so far appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). *Six* of those seven have comments from users indicating issues with the answer, which demonstrates why [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).